# how to get all ListBox items(not only selected items) on submit action in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how I get ALL `ListBox` values (not only selected items) on submit action in an `asp.net mvc2` project.

I'm using Ajax forms like

```
Ajax.BeginForm("actionname", new....)
```

I will get all items in the listbox only if i select all items in the list box.

Is there anyway to get all items, *not only selected items* in the lisbox in action page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not quite as easily done as you might think, since from the html-point of view, only the value that is selected in a drop down list is the value sent to the server on a submit.

However, if it is an alternative for you to send your data as json using jquery you can serialize the list box and send it over to the action along with your model.

One way to do it is like this:

Imagine you have the following Action in any given controller

`public ActionResult MyAction(string myDropDown, string myDropDownValues)`

And you have this Ajax form that you want to submit

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", new AjaxOptions()))
{ 
    @Html.Hidden("myDropDownValues")
    <select name="myDropDown" id="myDropDown">
        <option value="0">First</option>
        <option value="1">Second</option>
        <option value="2">Third</option>
        <option value="3">Fourth</option>
        <option value="4">Fifth</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
}
```

What you want to do now is hook into the submit event on the form like this: `$('form').submit(function(){});`

You should probably use a better selector if you have multiple forms on your page. Inside this submit event you can loop through your drop down list by using the `.each()` method and then compose the json inside that.

Once you've created your json you can add this to a hidden field to make it easier to handle on the server side.

It could end up looking sometwhat like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            var json = "";
            $("#myDropDown option").each(function () {
                value = $(this).val()
                text = $(this).html()

                if (json.length != 0) json += ",";

                json += value + ":" + text;
            });

            $('#myDropDownValues').val(json.toString());
        });
    });
</script>
```

when I submit my form now the string `myDropDownValues` has the following content:

`0:First,1:Second,2:Third,3:Fourth,4:Fifth`

Comment: @Null Pointer, Ah, my mistake. But good that you can adapt the idea :)

Comment: Another idea: 'manually' select all items in the submit function like that:

    `$("#myDropDown option").prop("selected", true)`.

Of course you'll loose the selection of the user! In my case I don't need it. But then you don't need to handle the json stuff. But of course with your answer you have all options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```